# Unenlightened monks indebtedness to the laity

Tags: the-buddha, pali-canon, reference-request, texts, laity

Was there an incident in the Buddhist scripture where the Buddha said of the indebtedness of the unenlightened monks to the laity that they should at least generate metta?

Comment: i can;t quite make sense of this question cos of the grammar, but it seems interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the Cūlaccharāsanghāta Sutta, this was preached to counter the  [Aggikkhandhopama Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an07/an07.068.yaho.html), which was said to frighten many monks back to lay life , or to "disrobe". This is supposedly ([link](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/c/cuula_ccharaasanghaata_s.htm)) said in the Manorathapūranī, the commentary by Buddhaghosa on the Aṅguttara-nikāya.